# NSTableview with RXSwift and RxCocoa for OSX

Tags: macos, reactive-programming, nstableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

How do I populate the *NSTableview* with an array using reactive framework? 
In iOS for UITableview:

```
self.viewModel.arrayElements.asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to: detailsTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "comment", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)){
            (row,element,cell) in
                 cell.addSubview(cellView)
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

how can i achieve the same for ***NSTableView***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar need, and solved it with a `BehaviorRelay` (using RxSwift 5).

The BehaviorRelay acts as a mediator so it's possible to use regular `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` protocols

The important part is the `self.detailsTableView.reloadData()` statement which tells the tableview to reload the data, it is not triggered automatically.

Something like this:

```swift
var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var tableDataRelay = BehaviorRelay(value: [Element]())

func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel.arrayElements.asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to: tableDataRelay).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    tableDataRelay
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe({ [weak self] evt in
            self.detailsTableView.reloadData()
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return tableDataRelay.value.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let element = tableDataRelay.value[row]
    let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView

    cellView?.textField?.stringValue = element.comment
    return cellView
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below, you should use drivers not observables

read this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

let data = Variable<[String]>([])
let bag  = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    data.asDriver.drive( tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "idenifier")){(row:Int, comment:String, cell:UITableViewCell) in
        cell.title = report
    }.disposed(by:bag)
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my modified post. I was referring to the appkit's NSTableview.

Comment: @Padma I am sorry I cant help you with that